# Concatenate two-line header by column

Tags: csv, unix, awk, command-line

I have a CSV file with a header consisting of two lines:

```
A, A, B, B, B
a, b, c, d, e
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

I'd like to concatenate the header to this form:

```
A_a, A_b, B_c, B_d, B_e
1,   2,   3,   4,   5
2,   3,   4,   5,   6
```

How to achieve that in command-line, using bash, sed, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = ", " }
     NR == 1{ split($0, a, ", "); next }
     NR == 2{ for(i=1; i <= NF; i++) $i = a[i]"_"$i }1' file
```

The output:

```
A_a, A_b, B_c, B_d, B_e
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Answer (score 1):

a bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

argfile=$1
line1=($(sed -n 1s/,//gp $argfile))
line2=($(sed -n 2p $argfile))
line12=()

for ((i=0; i<${#line1[*]}; i++))
do
    line12+=${line1[$i]}"_"${line2[$i]}" "
done
echo $line12
sed -n '3,$p' $argfile
```

The output:

```
A_a, A_b, B_c, B_d, B_e
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```